# What is {#{forceInclusion}#} using Angular in the header of an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've been using NG for about 1 year and I've NEVER seen this.

Here's the code in a webapp I'm working on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="Console">
        <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>My Project/title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> 
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
                <link href="css/import.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
                <link href="css/ng-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <link href="fonts/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <link href="fonts/font-lato.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                {#{force Inclusion '<!--[if IE 7]> <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/font-awesome.css"> <![endif]-->'}#}
                <!-- HTML5 shiv and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
                ç '<!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script> <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script> <![endif]-->'}#}
        </head>
        <body class="animated fadeInDown">
                <ng-include src="'part/header.html'"></ng-include>
                <ng-include src="'part/sidebar.html'"></ng-include>
                <div data-ui-view class="dashboard-wrapper"></div>
                <!--<div style="position:relative;"><div style="position:absolute; bottom:10px; left:10px;"><a href="{#{.branding.url}#}">Support URL</a></div></div>-->
                <ng-include src="'part/modal.html'"></ng-include>
                <action-pane></action-pane>
                <script src="/js/"></script> <!-- also, I've never seen this before -->
                <script> $("form").submit(function(){ return false; }); </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

That call to /js/ is throwing a **http://lwww.somedomain.com/js/** net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error in the console log and then this: **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.**  That makes sense since I just joined this team and I think what they are trying to do is tell the browser: Hey, get EVERYTHING in the js folder whether I need it or not.

But in all my years of writing JavaScript, I've never see that syntax.

So, two things:

The Forced Inclusion issue and the calling the entire JavaScript folder problem